# How to call fragment method from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

In my fragment I have a check if location is on all good, if location is off it sends the user to Settings screen.

If the user turn on the location from the settings screens, I want to call some methods in the fragment.

I tried to tackle this problem and I registered broadcast receiver to get updates when location is on/of -

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val intentFilter = IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)
    context.registerReceiver(locationBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
}


    override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    context?.unregisterReceiver(locationBroadcastReceiver)
}
```

And I have 2 problems with this approach:

A - The `OnReceive` override method gets called 3/4 every time I turned on/of location

B - How can I call fragment method from the receiver in order to continue with my code after user changes location provider state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FragmentManager.findfragmentbytag` for finding requried fragment then call the respective method